# Allow Registered/Logged in users to access folder files in directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

How to allow registered/logged in users only to access directly the URL for files and folders on web server?

Let's say I have folder like http://www.example.com/quiz/
that folder contains a lot of files, index.html and folders to load our quizzes.

if the user is not registered or logged in the url must not accessible.

Comment: You must take full control of routing. When you have full control of routing and files will be impossible to access directly, then you can use ACL to control behavior. This is a normal practice and you should search online for a solution. Come back with a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to redirect all requests to a PHP handler, using something like this in a `.htaccess` file or Apache configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /quiz/index.php [L,QSA]
```

(If you're not using Apache,  you'll have to look up how to do this for your particular server.)

And then in `/quiz/index.php` you would run whatever verification you normally use to check if a user is logged in, and if they are, output the contents of the file they were trying to retrieve (based on the URI request available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`). If not, send them to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, it helps, and this .htaccess solve my problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(js|gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ https://mywebsite.com/log-in/ [NC]
```